# How to align the plus sign under 1?

Tags: beamer, align

Code:

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} %For making Greek letters bold
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \setcounter{equation}{9}    
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
                \mathcal{H}\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t\right), u\left(t\right), \bm{\lambda}\left(t\right) \right) ={}& 1 + \lambda_1\left(t\right)x_2\left(t\right) \\ &+ \lambda_2\left(t\right)\left[-g - \frac{k}{x_3\left(t\right)}u\left(t\right)\right]+ \lambda_3\left(t\right)u\left(t\right).
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

How do I get the first plus sign on the second line to align with the 1 on the first line?

Comment: Have a look at the `split` environment

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that builds on your setup and works by inserting `\phantom{{}=1}` before the first `+` symbol on line 2. It "works" in terms of alignment, but now the equation is slightly too wide to let the equation number fit properly.

Anyway, I don't think it's that important to align the two `+` symbols. A simple `multline*` environment does a better job, in my opinion.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} %For making Greek letters bold
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright % no need to redefine '\left' and '\right'
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setcounter{equation}{9}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\mathcal{H}\left(\mathbf{x}\left(t\right), 
 u\left(t\right), \bm{\lambda}\left(t\right) \right) 
&= 1 + \lambda_1\left(t\right)x_2\left(t\right) \\ 
&\phantom{{}=1}+ \lambda_2\left(t\right)\left[-g - \frac{k}{x_3\left(t\right)}u\left(t\right)\right]+ \lambda_3\left(t\right)u\left(t\right).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{multline}
%% also replaced all 10 [!] instances of '\left(t\right)' with '(t)'.
\mathcal{H}\left(\mathbf{x}(t), u(t), \bm{\lambda}(t) \right) 
= 1 + \lambda_1(t)x_2(t) \\ 
+ \lambda_2(t)\left[-g - \frac{k}{x_3(t)}u(t)\right]+ \lambda_3(t)u(t).
\end{multline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

`aligned`, which you are using, does allow you to do that.

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} %For making Greek letters bold
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}
\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \setcounter{equation}{9}    
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}[b]
                \mathcal{H}\left(\mathbf{x}\mleft(t\mright), u\mleft(t\mright), 
                \bm{\lambda}\mleft(t\mright) \right) = 1 &+ \lambda_1\mleft(t\mright)x_2\mleft(t\mright) \\
                 &+ \lambda_2\mleft(t\mright)\left[-g -\frac{k}{x_3\mleft(t\mright)}u\mleft(t\mright)\right]\\
                 &+ \lambda_3\mleft(t\mright)u\mleft(t\mright).
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
        or
        \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}[b]
                \mathcal{H}\bigl(\mathbf{x}(t), u(t), 
                \bm{\lambda}(t) \bigr) 
                = 1 &+ \lambda_1(t)\,x_2(t) \\
                 &+ \lambda_2(t)\,\left[-g -\frac{k}{x_3(t)}u(t)\right]\\
                 &+ \lambda_3(t)\,u(t)\;.
            \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can change the alignment to `[t]` or leave it out to move the equation number. Since you are loading `mleftright` I took the opportunity to replace some `\left` and `\right`s to `\mleft` and `\mright`s, but you can just leave those out here. I personally would also add thin spaces to separate the functions (see the second version).

Comment: Sorry, I have seen the keywords b and t, but what do they mean?

Comment: @Superman They stand for `top` and `bottom` but ironically in different environments they can have a different detailed interpretation. Here it means basically align the equation baseline with the top or bottom line (loosely speaking).

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to get the bottom `+` sign to align with the one so that the equation number doesn’t drop.

Comment: @Superman Just use `\begin{aligned}` without any options. (I personally find this way of "aligning" the equation number really awful.)

Comment: Oh ok, I was trying to do so because in one of my main Beamer files, the equation was near the bottom of the slide, and the number was being cut off by the bottom edge

Comment: Then again, even if I try, the plus sign is always slightly off to the right relative to 1.  Personally, do you think that my original format excluding the equation number still looks fine without the alignment?

Comment: @Superman - Your comment "the plus sign is always slightly off to the right relative to 1" makes me wonder which TeX distribution you employ. Which TeX distribution do you use, and when was it updated last?

Comment: TeX distribution? I am not sure if this would answer your question, but I am using TeXStudio (with MikTeX 2.9).